# PostgreSql. Вставляем сущность с поиском свободного id в таблицу без auto_increment

Tags: postgresql, insert

Добрый день!

Допустим есть простая таблица `entity` с полями `id` и `name`. Поле `id` без `auto_increment`. И есть сущность с полями `id = 6` и `name = "Просто любое имя"`. Необходимо вставить эту сущность в таблицу таким образом, чтоб был выполнен поиск свободного идентификатора, начиная с текущего. (В данном случае от 6 и выше).

Удалось найти поиск свободного значения на [Хабре](https://habrahabr.ru/post/228099/):

```
SELECT (`entity`.`id`+1) as `free_id`
FROM `entity`
WHERE (
    SELECT 1 FROM `entity` as `et` WHERE `et`.`id` = (`entity`.`id` + 1)
) IS NULL
ORDER BY `entity`.`id`
LIMIT 1
```

Итого есть 3 вещи, которые я недопонимаю:

1. В какой `WHERE`(внутреннего подзапроса или внешнего) добавить условие **AND et.id >= $id**, чтоб идентификатор искался с текущего?
2. Как связать этот поиск идентификатора с вставкой записи
   `INSERT INTO 'entity' VALUES ('$id', '$name')` чтоб все выполнялось в рамках одного запроса?
3. Если сделать все одним запросом, будет ли достигнута изоляция этой операции? Допустим два администратора одновременно вставляют две сущности с `id = 6`. Будут ли последовательно найдены **разные** свободные идентификаторы?

Comment: 1. Во внешний. 2. Написать insert прямо перед select вместо фразы values будет сам select. 3. Нет, двум транзакциям может быть выдан 1 id. Для этого собственно автоинкремент и придуман, потому что единственная ему альтернатива - блокирование всей таблицы перед началом операции

Comment: Можете немного пояснить? 2. Если написать весь селект вместо `VALUES`, то как же будет записан `name`? Или Вы имеете ввиду весь селект вместо части `'$id'`? 3. Разве таблица не блокируется на запись, при другой записи в нее?

Comment: в select можно выбирать константы, вот тот select 1 внутри ведь не колонку получает а 1. `insert into ... select id, '$name' ...`. При вставке блокировка будет только на новой записи, остальную часть таблицы можно читать. Хотя наличие этой заблоченной записи должно приостановить select который на нее наткнется. НО блокировка будет взята после того как получен ID и никто не мешает двум запросам получить один ID а потом начать вставку

Comment: Спасибо, Ваши комментарии были ценны для меня. Не хотите оформить ответ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот такой запрос позволит безопасно получить id и вставить запись с гарантией уникальности ID в postgresql:

```
with Q (id) as(
 select id+1 from test1 A
   where id >= $id
     and not exists(select 1 from test1 B where B.id=A.id+1)
   order by id
   limit 1
   FOR UPDATE
)
 insert into test1(id, name)
 select id,'$name'
   from Q
```

Основной элемент запроса `FOR UPDATE` он заблокирует запись с предыдущим ID и таким образом не позволит другой транзакции получить тот же самый ID до тех пор, пока первая транзакция целиком не закончена.

P.S. обратите внимание, запрос не вставит запись и при этом завершится без ошибок в случае, если подходящих ID в БД не будет найдено. т.е. например в случае если последний ID в БД меньше переданного `$id`. Так что по окончании запроса проверяйте количество вставленных записей (у драйверов работы с БД есть соответствующие переменные)

Comment: Существует ли механизм, позволяющий оставить переданный `id` по-умолчанию, в случае. когда последний `id` в базе меньше переданного `id`?

Comment: Будут ли у меня проблемы, если я заменю на `where (id >= $id
     and not exists(...)) or id = $id - 1`?

Comment: @Oleg Конечно будут. фильтр вернет записи по первому условию и все записи по второму условию, после чего возьмет с минимальным id и что то мне подсказывает это будет как раз $id-1. вам тогда надо обеспечить, что бы order by вернул первой записью именно по первому условию, т.е. писать там первым делом какой нибудь `case when id>=$id then 0 else 1 end`. ну и условие id=$id-1 оно же только одну запись вернет и если ее не будет, то опять же на выходе ничего не будет. А если таблица пуста то первую запись таким запросом вы в принципе не вставите

Comment: Понял. Буду дальше разбираться.