# PostgreSQL. Обработать возвращаемое значение из подзапроса

Tags: postgresql, insert

Вопрос вытекает из моего [раннее заданного вопроса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/728331/postgresql-%D0%92%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D1%81%D1%83%D1%89%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-id-%D0%B2-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%83-%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%B7-auto-increm/728357?noredirect=1#comment1102929_728357).

Есть запрос:

```
with Q (id) as(
 select id from test1 A
   where id >= $id
     and not exists(select 1 from test1 B where B.id=A.id+1)
   order by id
   limit 1
   FOR UPDATE
)
 insert into test1(id, name)
 select id+1,'$name'  // Эта строка
   from Q
```

Как можно проверить, вернет ли подзапрос какой-то идентификатор, и если нет, то подставить значение по-умолчанию, например 10.

Что-то вроде такого:

```
insert into test1(id, name)
  select coalesce(id+1, 10),'$name'  // Так не работает
    from Q
```

Или такого:

```
insert into test1(name, id)
 values('$name', coalesce(select id+1 from Q, 10)  // Ругается "неверное положение select"
```

Comment: `insert ... select coalesce(MAX(id)+1, 10)...`

Comment: Можете объяснить, почему с `MAX` заработало? Это какой-то трюк?

Comment: Оформите ответ?

Comment: Сделайте пустую таблицу. Выполните просто `select id` из нее, разумеется не получите ни одной строки. Теперь сделайте `select MAX(id)` из таблицы, получите одну строку со значением NULL. появилась агрегатная функция, был выполнен неявный group by и выведена единственная итоговая строка, вместо строк данных, итог же появляется вне зависимости от наличия входных записей. А нам того и надо, что бы была ровно одна строка, не важно с каким содержимым

Comment: Спасибо за разъяснение

Answer (score 0):

```
/*попробовать так(postgreSQL не установлена, проверить не могу, извините)*/
with Q (id) as(
 select CASE WHEN id IS NULL THEN 10 ELSE id END id
 from test1 A
where id >= $id
 and not exists(select 1 from test1 B where B.id=A.id+1)
order by id
limit 1
FOR UPDATE
)
insert into test1(id, name)
 select id+1,'$name'  // Эта строка
from Q
```

Comment: так точно не прокатит. ваш case (который заменяет функцию coalsece) новых строк не породит, а проблема в отсутствии строк результата

Comment: Согласен. Если так смотреть на задачу, то ваш вариант наиболее краток и предпочтителен.

Comment: ну кроме агрегатных функций ничего не может создать строку из ничего. (Если конечно не прибегать к громоздким манипуляциям с UNION и хитрой сортировкой)